# Bing Maps Silverlight Control, System.Windows.Browser .dll

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

When I'm deploying application to WP7, application throws exception:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type 'Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Map' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. [Line: 24 Position: 16] ---> System.MissingMethodException: File or assembly name 'System.Windows.Browser, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7CEC85D7BEA7798E', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

When I'm deploying same application to emulator or mobile device(in debug mode)  everything works as expected.

Do you have any idea how to make it work without debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

First, check if System.Windows.Browser is referenced in your project, and if it already was, check in its property tab that it's marked as "Copy". The issue seems to be that your app is unable to find it at runtime.

If a System.Windows.Browser file is referenced, check if it's the one the control requires (2.0.5.0)

Comment: Hi, System.Windows.Browser is referenced and marked as "Copy". And because of this message I think control requires this reference. Or it is possible that it doesn't?